# Android Sensors + ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

I am trying to create an app where it displays all sensors's names of the device in ListView and then when clicking on the name, it opens another screen with all the information from the sensor.

I have created the listView but I am struggling with how to pass the information to another screen using Intent.

what is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

It can depend on the type of the data you want to pass and the way your layout is created.

In general you have some string you want to pass around and an activity that starts another activity with

```
String someValue = "some value";
Intent i = new Intent(this, OtherActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

Now, you can add some stuff to this intent that it should take to the activity it's starting:

```
String someValue = "some value";
Intent i = new Intent(this, OtherActivity.class);
i.putExtra("some key", someValue);
startActivity(i);
```

Then in your new activity you can (in the `onCreate()`) retrieve it with

```
String someValue = getIntent().getStringExtra("some key");
```

Comment: My data is the list of the sensors